# Android : Preloading / Caching images in Glide ,Image blinks while loading

Tags: android, android-glide

I am developing a game and at the start of every scene I would like to preload the images I will be using so it doesn't do the blinking everytime I load the images with Glide.

The following is my code. Basically I just loop Glide load into the imageview and the image should get cached, at least that's what I think it should do :

```
for (int i : images) {
    Glide.with(this).load(i).into(imageView);
}

imageView.setDrawable(null);
```

This doesn't seem to work though. It still does the blink every first time the image is loaded. Meaning the image didn't get cached. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the glide is inside the for loop right? it will replace the image i times in the same image view. if you have to see all the images ,you have to use a Handler just like i did in my example.the image may be blinking because of the for loop

Answer (score 3):

if you want to cach the image then you may have to add

```
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
```

so that it will not blink after loading, please check the below Code for references.

```
Glide.with(this)
                .load(i)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                .error(R.drawable.default_image)
                .override(200, 200)
                .centerCrop()
                .dontAnimate()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
```

and if you have to load images one by one in the same image view just like the stuff which the usual game loading's do, just check this

```
 int delay = 1000;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //do something
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);

                if(i<imageArray.length){
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load(i)
                        .placeholder(menuIcons[i])
                        .override(200, 200)
                        .centerCrop()
                            .dontAnimate()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into(myImage);

                    i=i+1;
                }else{
                    i=0;
                      Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load(i)
                        .placeholder(menuIcons[i])
                        .override(200, 200)
                        .centerCrop()
                            .dontAnimate()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into(myImage);

                    i=i+1;
                }
            }
        }, delay);
```

NOTE : you should add android:largeHeap="true" to your manifest file for avoiding Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError , just like this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Still blinks on the first load of an image

Comment: the glide is inside the for loop right? it will replace the image i times in the same image view. if you have to see all the images ,you have to use a Handler just like i did in my example.the image may be blinking because of the for loop